# What are the acceptable types used in the Class TypeMap in Cake 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

## Situation

using cake 3.2.4

Was using the method `addDefaults()` to set the type `decimal`. Was wondering the following:

1. what other types are there that I can set?
2. is it possible to set precision and scale when setting decimal in the method `addDefaults()`

## Code that prompted that thinking

```
       $this->paginate['fields'] = [
            'id', 'title', 
            'start' => 'start_date', 
            'end' => 'end_date', 
            'revenue', 
            'costs' => 'total_costs', 'collections'
        ];
        $paginationQuery  = $event->subject()->query;

        $paginationQuery
        ->selectTypeMap()
        ->addDefaults([
            'start' => 'datetime',
            'end' => 'datetime',
            'costs' => 'decimal'
        ]);
```

## What I tried

I tried researching the docs

http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.TypeMap.html#_addDefaults

and also the class itself http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/source-class-Cake.Database.TypeMap.html#17-149

To no avail.

Comment: Why do you need to transform the value additionally to casting it? Shouldn't `total_costs` already be formatted properly?

Comment: Zero does not appear with 2 decimal places. E.g. 0 instead of 0.00 hence was thinking abt precision and scale

Comment: That's how PHP works, empty decimals are not going to be shown, this is something that you should handle when outputting the data **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/number.html#formatting-numbers**

Comment: I see. In that case, my original question remained. Where is the list of acceptable types that can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what other types are there that I can set?

The available types can be found in the cookbook

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Data Types](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#data-types)**

and in the source

- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/3.2.5/src/Database/Type**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.5/src/Database/Type.php#L27-L64**

> is it possible to set precision and scale when setting decimal in the method addDefaults()

As mentioned in the comments, PHP swallows trailing zero decimals, that's just how it works, if you want to "keep" them, then you should format the numbers when outputting them.

**[Cookbook > Number > Formatting Numbers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/number.html#formatting-numbers)**