# Cakephp3: Result of CASE statement being forced to string, need integer

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am generating a case statement to return either 0 or 1:

```
$desc_case = $q->newExpr()
    ->addCase(
            [$q->newExpr()->add(["description IS" => NULL])],
            [0,1],
            ["integer","integer"]
            );
$q = $q->select(["has_desc" => $desc_case]);
```

Which results in the following correct SQL:

```
SELECT [fields removed for clarity], (CASE WHEN (description) IS NULL THEN :c0 ELSE :c1 END) AS `has_desc` FROM skills Skills
```

I've turned hydration off, and retrieved the result with

```
->hydrate(false)->toArray();
```

The result of the CASE statement is returned as a string- either "0" or "1" - which is messing up logic downstream.

I've traced the execution code as best I can, and it looks like CakePHP is using the type names passed to correctly bind the values, but nowhere does the type make its way into the TypeMap used for mapping output.

An easy workaround is to adjust the values after the fact (which I'm doing), but I'd like to make this work as expected on principle... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type information passed to `addCase()` is only ment to be used for input casting, ie the values passed will be bound as the given types. The return values, ie the values being selected via the compiled `CASE` statement, are in no way being affected.

If you want to affect the type used for casting selected values of columns that do not exist in the schema (note that changing the schema will also affect other parts of the ORM and the query builder), then you have to change the type map accordingly, for example:

```
$query
    ->getSelectTypeMap()
    ->addDefaults([
        'has_desc' => 'integer'
    ]);
```

See also

- **[Cakephp-3.x: How to change the data type of a selected alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650306/cakephp-3-x-how-to-change-the-data-type-of-a-selected-alias/35652166)**